# [ww-2160 struts] Is <s:property value=%{'xyz'}>

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, code-injection

This is regarding the security flaw in OGNL evaluation is struts.
Can someone give an example how this is exploited?

Imagine I have a request parameter and server returns this back to the client:
`http://test/xyz=test`

I have a variable named `xyz` with getter and setter in action class, and in JSP I have:

```
<s:property value="%{xyz}" />
```

If someone uses the URL `http://test/xyz=@System@exit(0)` what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the ticket you linked to was fixed in 2007. I don't know what exactly the problem was back then, but it doesn't appear to be relevant anymore.

> If someone uses the URL http://test/xyz=@System@exit(0) what happens?

Your JSP page would output the string literal `@System@exit(0)`.

OGNL expressions are processed inside the Struts2 tags. In this case, the string literal `%{xyz}` is passed to the `setValue(String)` method of `PropertyTag`. Inside that tag, that string is evaluated against the value stack to produce the resulting value of `@System@exit(0)`. That value is then output.